# How to detect how many objects are in the display object? (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm making a game in which coins are randomly generated. Once a coin (multiple on the screen at once) is collected it respawns in another location. I have a few ways of doing this, but to advance I need these questions answered:

1. How would I go about detecting how many objects are in the display list?
2. How to detect when an object is removed from the display list?

All answers are appreciated in advance.

Comment: That depends entirely on the setup of your project. with `[yourDisplayObject].numChildren` you will get the number of children any given display list has. And you are removing those Objects from the display list yourself with removeChild, so it is up to you to 'detect' it. You could fire and event every time you remove and Object, for example.

Answer (score 1):

for detecting number of objects, you could do a recursive function that loops through each all children, and returns the count

```
import flash.display.DisplayObjectContainer;

function numAllChildren($do:DisplayObjectContainer):int{
    var $c:int = 0;
    for (var $i:int = 0; $i < $do.numChildren; $i++){
        if($do.getChildAt($i) is DisplayObjectContainer){
            $c += numAllChildren($do.getChildAt($i) as DisplayObjectContainer);
        }
        $c++;
    }
    return $c;
}

trace(numAllChildren(_mc));
```

To see if there has been a change, you'd use an event listener on ADDED and/or REMOVED. But you'll need to put it on every DisplayObject
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#ADDED
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#REMOVED

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here : [DisplayObjectContainer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html)

It contains all what you need, for your 2nd question see `Events` part.